# createIndex for pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

i can create index using mongo shell. i used `db.db_list.createIndex({firstName:"text",secondName:"text",thirdName:"text",fourthName:"text"})`

but i can't use that for pymongo, because that's not work for me

```
db.db_list.create_index({"firstName":"text","secondName":"text","thirdName":"text","fourthName":"text"})
```

i have error raise TypeError("if no direction is specified, "

> `TypeError: if no direction is specified, key_or_list must be an instance of list`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `pymongo.TEXT` enum to create text indexes.

Also, for some reason the index definition needs to be sent as a list of tuples.

Try this:

```
from pymongo import TEXT

...


db.db_list.create_index([("firstName", TEXT), ("secondName", TEXT), ("thirdName", TEXT), ("fourthName", TEXT))
```

You can check for more examples [here](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/94221/pymongo.TEXT)

Comment: Thank you very much.that's really helpful to me